# How to highlight feature from attributr table from the selected features?

Tags: qgis

We have option in Arcgis to highlight select/ unselect highlight feature from selected feature from attribute table.

IS there a way to do this in QGIS ??

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Open the Attribute table and select a row by clicking on the row number:

[image]

You may use the Ctrl or Shift key when you click to add or remove items from the selection.